# Choosing dynamic Image Compression Quality rate for different images

Tags: python, image-processing, compression

I have some questions about choosing **Image Compression Quality** dynamicly. So what does mean?

For example, I have an Image, that look like sunset, everywhere is nearly red-orange, or an image of blue sky. Like these images, I should choose %70-80 rate for Image Compression Quality.

In other hand, think we have an image most of it white, so we can use %30-40 quality for it, because white images don't be hardy when compressing.

So, I need to detect this, this image should be ok with this rate, other image should be ok with this rate. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Yea, I will do it with Python. I have a solution but I don't know it is good. Maybe, get all pixel's color and create an union color by these color infos. So, I can get all colors avarage? This is good?

Comment: What do you expect from such an algorithm? Why not use 80% all the time - an image that holds only little information might already get compressed a lot using that quality setting